# Is there a word or phrase (other than euphemism/innuendo) for using one word/phrase to mean another?

Tags: meaning, word-choice

Recently, on an episode of a TV series I watch, one of the female characters asks a male character, "Do you want some bourbon?", when what she means is, "Do you want to have sex with me?". Is there another word/phrase (other than euphemism/innuendo) to describe her question (preferably one not limited to the particular context of sex)?

Edit: ["coffee"](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NPqBV6LhuW8) could also have worked in the character's sentence.

Comment: So you are looking for a synonym to "euphemism"? What's wrong with "euphemism"?

Comment: Nothing is *wrong* with 'euphemism'. I would like a word that isn't as commonly used, for the sake of variety.

Comment: So... you want an uncommon synonym for "euphemism"?

Comment: [_Metaphor_](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/Metaphors.pdf).

Comment: I'm leaving this one to community consensus. Whichever anwer reaches five votes or is most popular by Sunday @ 20:00 SAST gets accepted if it's workable.

Comment: Popularity is no guarantor of correctness, certainly not of suitability-to-purpose-on-hand.

Comment: @Kris Indeed popularity by itself is not a suitable criterion, which is why I've specified "if it's workable".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Such an expression might be a **double entendre.**

Wikipedia defines this as

> a figure of speech in which a spoken phrase is devised to be understood in either of two ways. Typically one of the interpretations is rather obvious whereas the other is more subtle. The more subtle of the interpretations is sometimes sexually suggestive. It may also convey a message that would be socially awkward, or even offensive, to state directly. (The Oxford English Dictionary describes a double entendre as being used to "convey an indelicate meaning".)

Answer (score 5):

**Figure of speech** may work, although it is more than one word. **Idiom** may be another. **Metaphor** may be more specific.

Comment: upvote for idiom.

Comment: +1 Metaphor is more like it. It's not an idiom, not figure of speech either.

Answer (score 1):

I have never heard of *bourbon* being equated with *sex* as a standard euphemism, but you might consider the expressions below to describe this:

**Speaking in code**: using one's own code words to refer to something else so that only those who know code can decipher its actual meaning. ([Here's an example.](http://forum.wordreference.com/showthread.php?t=2316992)) Not the same as [code switching](http://www.npr.org/blogs/codeswitch/2013/04/13/177126294/five-reasons-why-people-code-switch).

> The reason you couldn't understand what he said is because he was speaking in code. He didn't want the children to know what he was talking about.

**Private language**: words used differently than for their commonly understood meanings, or using non-sense sounding words for the same purpose.

> Those two have their own private language. Half the time, I don't know what they are saying to each other.

Comment: Have you not heard of "a night cap" (drink before bed) being used for the same thing? It crops up at least once in James Bond films.

Comment: That's a little more specific, and if I were saying it to Ursula Andress, neither one of us would find it ambiguous. But James Bond is better at this than that. If he told M he was having a little scotch, I'm sure the contextual pun would be obvious.

Comment: "James, what *are* you doing?" "Just keeping the British end up."

Answer (score 1):

Having rejected *innuendo* and *euphemism*, you've pretty well run out of single-word answers that do the job. But if a word-pair is acceptable, you could consider the word *veiled* combined with another that points more specifically at the meaning you intend: *veiled invitation, veiled threat, veiled challenge...*

Comment: While I ultimately went with 'double entendre', 'veiled invitation' would also have worked. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

"Metonymy":

> a figure of speech that consists of the use of the name of one object or concept for that of another to which it is related, or of which it is a part, as “scepter” for “sovereignty”, or “the bottle” for “strong drink”, or “count heads (or noses)” for “count people”.

Source: [Dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/Metonymy?s=t)

Comment: I'm not sure that's quite what I'm looking for, as it mentions a close correlation between the two (one being an attribute of/representative part of the other). I'm thinking more along the lines of 'allusion' or 'inference'.

Comment: -1 What *is* "Metonymy"? Without that how can this count for an answer?

Answer (score 0):

Imply:

1. to indicate or suggest without being explicitly stated

Implication:

1. something implied or suggested as naturally to be inferred or understood